# Could metal powders replace metal wires?

Tags: wire

My headphones broke recently due to what I suspect was work hardening, and I was wondering, could a sealed tube of rubber filled with a powder replace wiring? Products would be more durable as the wires wouldn't break due to work hardening.

Comment: Your better wire for headphones and the like is "tinsel wire" which consists of a thin tinsel-like strip of some alloy wrapped around a fiber cord.  The cord provides the tensile strength and the "tinsel" is incredibly flexible.  The difficult with this wire is that it cannot be soldered but must be crimp terminated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless the tube is filled with something like powdered gold, the surface of the individual particles will eventually oxidize, and the resistance of the "wire" will skyrocket. Even without this effect, the resistance of a collection of powder which is left loose (not sintered) shows various weird electrical effects. Google on "coherer" for a prime example.

Answer (score 2):

There are metal powder-filled elastomers that are used for electrically-conductive gasketing, but their resistivity is not nearly as low as a solid metal. They're meant for applications where the current flows primarily across their width, not along their length.

The usual technique for highly-flexible wires is to wrap a thin ribbon of metal in a spiral around a tough (but nonconductive) fiber core. This was invented by the telephone company many years ago for handset cords, and is sometimes used in other applications such as headphones as well. Making good connections to such wires can be a headache, though. It's usually done with custom crimped-on contacts.